# Keyboard issues in Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: keyboard

I have a HP Envy Laptop that opens multiple Bing browsers every 5-10 Keystrokes. I've tried Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Firefox, Internet Explorer and they all do the same thing. I've run a virus check, downloaded Malware programs all have come back with no issues. I've run chkdsk and again all came back with no errors.

Any help with this?

Comment: Have you tried another (USB) keyboard?

Comment: Is there any particular key pressed when this occurs? I find it bizarre to blame this on the keyboard. Does this also happens when you on desktop using arrow keys to navigate icons?

Comment: Did you reset all Internet options from Windows to default and disabled all addons?

Comment: I think a lot of people are looking at this an tilting their heads. The keyboard aspect seems a little odd. It's more likely you already have a browser open and that over time is opening new windows. Just for clarity, can you start the computer in safe mode with network. Only open a new text file and test that theory that your keyboard opens a new window?

Answer (score -1):

Run MSRT (Malicious Software Removal Tool).

Check for any malicious files and also go to properties of the browsers shortcut.

1. Go to shortcut **Properties**
2. Go to **Shortcut tab**, Target location is properly located.

Sometimes you can see additional URL after the program location (for example: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "www.bing.com" "google.com")`. Remove the URLs from the Target which may redirect it.